# (PHP) How do I make bold words from a text, that start with a specific letter?

Tags: php

I am pretty new to PHP, and I can't seem to make this work...
I need to make all the words that start with a letter D in bold, and count how many were bolded. I tried using patterns, but I don't undestand how to make that  happen :/
Code I tried:

```
$pattern = "/(\b)(d\w+\b)/";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

it does find all arrays with letter D, but i need it to output the whole $text, and have words bolded with used pattern.. Anyone can help? ;D Thanks in advance

Result:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sit [1] => sed [2] => quis [3] => sint [4] => sunt [5] =>
(it's with a different letter tho)

Result wanted: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed **do** eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et **dolore** magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

All words starting with D are bold.

Comment: If you show us examples of the input and required output you will stand more chance of an answer

Comment: Try with https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php. Replace your founds with *(found)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough to accomplish with [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback). You almost had it right with the regex -- note that you don't need to have capture groups for `\b` word boundaries (not the least since they are "non-items" and would only be captured as blanks!). This would do it:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/\b(d\w+)\b/i', function($match) {
    return "<b>{$match[1]}</b>";
}, $string, -1, $count);
```

This function conveniently takes a referenced argument returning the number of replacements done. I have also added in the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching, in case your lipsum should start with `Dolor`. This results in the following variables:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed <b>do</b> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <b>dolore</b> magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

$count = 3;
```

**Edit:** Not sure why I initially wrote this answer using a callback... You can also accomplish this, including getting the count, with the simple [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace), as follows:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b(d\w+)\b/i', '<b>$1</b>', $string, -1, $count);
```

In any case, I'm leaving the callback version in place, in case you need to do something more complex with the result (e.g. also log replaced words for reference).

Comment: Thank you! Did just want I needed!

Comment: Excellent. Updated the answer FYI, with the simpler way to do it.